# How to Access .Net web app from IP Address?

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-core, sql-server-express

i am new to .net i have web application which is working fine , the problem is that i want to open it from `Ip Address` instead of `localhost` so that everyone on LAN can access it. I replace the `localhost` with `IP` in `launchsetting.json` It open the web application using `IP` but then it wont connect to `Database` but when i open it using `localhost` it works fine with `Database`. Any help is really appreciated.

Database : SQLEXPRESS 18.

This is my `launchsetting.json` file :

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51911",
      "sslPort": 44374
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ReactC_MDSS": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my appsetting.json file for DB connection string :

```
{
  "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "patientDB": "Data Source=DESKTOP-FE7Q19U\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MDSS;Integrated Security=True"
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not make sense, the launching url should be localhost because your build is deployed in the localhost. If you want to build a demo server in LAN for the other developers to access it, just go to the host (whose IP is what you want) and deploy your build there (don't need to change the launching url, just note about the port which should be open). That may require a db server installed as well (or adjust your sql connection string accordingly).

Comment: Hi @wraith123 456, you can see this [thread](https://forums.asp.net/t/1041300.aspx?Can+we+access+an+asp+net+website+using+IP+Address+in+an+LAN+Network) may helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In order for members on your LAN to access your app, you need to do a couple things.

First off, you need to make sure the port isnt blocked by your firewall. Double check this guide to ensure (for windows 10): https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html

Next up, you need to find out what your devices local IP is that your router assigned it.

127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 is synonymous with Localhost, and can only be used by applications from the same computer. You need to find your local IP, heres a guide for that:

https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-local-ip-address

Then you're other devices will need to connect to your website via `Your.Local.Ip`:`YourPort`

This should theoretically work, but you may also need to double check your router settings as well, some routers might have additional firewalls setup to block port traffic that you need to configure to allow that port to let traffic through as well.

An alternative approach is to use a program like nginx to reverse proxy, and instead open up port 80 or port 443 (http and https respectively), and then reverse proxy from those ports, to the localhost port you have the web app running on.